# Is possible to create water?

Tags: particle-physics, water, molecules

Theoretically is relatively easy to create water, because it is formed by only the hydrogen and one oxygen molecules.

I know that the oxygen and hydrogen is highly flammable, and to union the molecules we needs a very high energy.

Those are the reasons that we are not currently creating water or have more than it?

**EDIT**

I forgot to say: I know that we have a lot of water in the world, but, my doubt is because I was thinking, -not worth creating water than desalinize, for example?

Another way to think, is because the universe have a lot of hydrogen instead of water.

Comment: Why would you create water? We have plenty. Where we don't have water, I doubt we have pure oxygen and hydrogen stashed up.

Comment: Burn hydrogen, get water. We have a lot of water. We don't have a lot of hydrogen. I don't understand this question - or what it has to do with physics...

Comment: Every cell in your body creates water all the time. As an animal, you breathe in $\mathrm{O_2}$ and eat food that to a first approximation has the chemical formula $\mathrm{CH_2O}$ (e.g. sugar is $\mathrm{C_6H_2O}$). Your respiration is a complex series of chemical reactions that convert these into $\mathrm{CO_2}$ and $\mathrm{H_2O}$. Making water is how you live.

Comment: Note that "high energy" means something very different in chemistry (the actual subject of this question) than in particle physics. The combustion of hydrogen and oxygen to create water is a very, *very*, ***very*** low energy event by particle physics standards.

Comment: Second note, we are in no danger of running out of water. Never have been and won't be for a very long time. We can reasonable be concerned about running out of potable water in various places.

Comment: Creating water would require Baryogenesis, which is as far as we know, impossible (ignoring the fact that water exists, and therefore it should be possible)...

Comment: As an interesting tidbit, semiconductor fabs 'create' water all the time - if you do a wet oxidation of silicon, the water is actually made by burning hydrogen and oxygen.  This is done because the gases can be made to 6-9's or better purity, which is much better than you can get water. Deionized water is not actually very pure (just low in ions), and distilled water would grab lots of impurities from the plumbing.

Comment: @Floris if u burn hydrogen you get only 1 molecule of water correct?

Comment: All you, sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: A more clever way is to use a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell instead of igniting hydrogen. Make the chemical energy usable as electricity.

Answer (score 2):

In my first year at secondary school we got to ignite hydrogen in a glass flask, then test the droplets that formed on the wall of the flask to show they were water. That was at age 11. Actually, in this day and age of safety legislation I'm not sure whether pupils are still encouraged to make explosions.

Anyhow, making water from hydrogen and air is dead easy. Sadly it's not a cost effective way to make water unless you have a free supply of hydrogen.

Re your edit: there is enough hydrogen in, for example, Jupiter to provide all the fresh water mankind could ever want. We just need to find a way to get the hydrogen from Jupiter to the Earth.

Comment: Asking if Toluene used in an experiment for fire prevention could also be used to create explosives was answered by a short pause and a "no" by my chemistry teacher back when I was in school. I conclude that making explosions is indeed not encouraged.

Comment: @Name: Toluene and concentrated nitric acid. What could possibly go wrong? :-)

Comment: Thankfully I had a dad who was trained as a chemical engineer before WW2. His idea of "analysis" of an unknown chemical was "smell it, taste it" - very effective. I made 8 foot purple flames, discovered nitric acid turns your skin yellow, and that burning sulphur stings your eyes like crazy. And lots more. Can't even but those chemicals any more. SIGH. Oh - did I mention that 8 foot flames can set fire to the upstairs curtains when the window is open?